# Полная загрузка страницы (загружается скриптом)

Tags: html, javascript

Сайт http://a-s-buro.com/
Дело в том,что он загружается каким-то фрэймворком наверное.
И некоторые скрипты несмотря на строчку

```
$(document).ready(function() {}
```

выполняются раньше, чем загрузится ДОМ.

Как можно решить эту проблему? На ум приходит только setTimeout, но это ни есть хорошо.

Comment: Каким образом вы об это узнали? Если так, как работает добрая тонна анимации? Единственное что прелоудится на данном лендинге это картинки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Событие **ready** не может (теоретически) срабатывать раньше загрузки dom-дерева.
2) Попробуйте использовать событие **onload**, оно срабатывает позже, когда загружен еще и весь контент (например, картинки).

Answer (score 0):

как вариант попробуйте все скрипты вынести в конец <body>
больше с текущем описанием не скажешь.

Comment: Я же ссылку на сайт дал